# QT Subdir- Undefined reference to main  - Error

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a simple QT subdir project with the structure of

```
TestProject/
    TestProject.pro
    Subdir1/
            Subdir1.pro
        sources/
            main.cpp
    Subdir2/
        Subdir2.pro
        headers/
            mainwindow.h
        sources/
            mainwindow.cpp
```

Here are my .pro files
TestProject.pro

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS += \
    Subdir1 \
    Subdir2
```

Subdir1.pro

```
SOURCES += \
main.cpp
```

Subdir2.pro

```
QT += sql

SOURCES += \
    mainwindow.cpp \
HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h \
```

When I try to run the application I get the following error:

```
(.text+0x18):-1: error: undefined reference to `main'
```

I am using the Qt Creator IDE on Ubuntu 12.04.
I have spent all morining trying to figure this out, What must I put in the .pro files in order for Qt to be able to build the project?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your second target is missing a main function. Easiest way to fix that is to have all files in one .pro file. Alternatively you can put mainwindow.h/cpp into a separate library and link that in subdir2.pro, which seems unnecessarily complex here though.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld - I am not sure I understand.. Have only one .pro file for the whole project?  If not what folder would you recommomend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is build all your source files into one executable.  This is not what the subdirs template is for, it's for creating a single Makefile which builds several different targets (for example two different executables, or an executable and a library).

What you probably want is either to just have a single .pro file with e.g.

`SOURCES = Subdir1/mainwindow.cpp Subdir1/main.cpp`

Or you can make the subdir pro files into (by convention) .pri files.  Then at the top level you would just do:

```
include(Subdir1/Subdir1.pri)
include(Subdir2/Subdir2.pri)
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, I think you understand what I am trying to do and put me on the right path!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add your *Subdir.pro* files into your *TestProject.pro* file explicitly:

```
OTHER_FILES += \
    Subdir1/Subdir1.pro\
    Subdir2/Subdir2.pro\
```

so Qt knows there are subprojects.