# Custom Qt widget example in Qt Creator errors

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, custom-widgets, qtwidgets

I'm a Qt beginner, I have the 5.2.1 version and I was trying to learn Qt/QML from a book on Github. However, this is one of the most basic examples:

```
#ifndef CUSTOMWIDGET_H
#define CUSTOMWIDGET_H

#include <QtWidgets>

class CustomWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CustomWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
   void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
   void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
private:
     QPoint m_lastPos;
};

#endif // CUSTOMWIDGET_H
```

And here are the errors I get:

> ln function `_start'
>
> undefined reference to `main'
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I have no idea what any of these mean, so any help would be appreciated. I made the project as a Qt Quick Application.

These are included in the `.pro` file

```
QT += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

Comment: Probably you copied *.h and *.cpp files belong to the CustomWidget class and didn't copy main.cpp so linker cannot find entry point

Comment: Yes, that's what silly me did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should go to google and look for the errors, you can find them and the solution, and some solutions are here in stackoverflow too.

For what I can help and hope it helps you:

1. `ln function _start'` With only that I don't know what does it mean, can you copy the full error? Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116399/crt1-o-in-function-start-undefined-reference-to-main-in-linux) can help you
2. `undefined reference to main'` Basically you are doing a example in a new project I supose so there is no main() function, which is basic for any program to run. You can add a main.cpp or declare it globaly like `void main() {}`Try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177241/qt-subdir-undefined-reference-to-main-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861783/using-library-in-qtcreator-undefined-reference)
3. `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`  means that something was wrong (there are errors before this line), so that's why is the last error.